# android studio version control can't ignore file

Tags: android, android-studio, svn

I have add ignore file in preference ,but the ignore file still need commit.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can be wrong, but as I remember, rules of ignore file don't work if you pushed files into repository before. So you can try to remove this files, push commit and after it rules of ignore file will be applied.